# Use a robot to type characters in Java

Tags: java, keypress, awtrobot

I know how to have Robot simulate a Y keypress like so:

```
    Robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_Y);
```

But how do I get Robot to press a quote and period?:

```
".
```

Can anyone provide me some reference page or sample code?

Comment: you mean like System.out.print("\""); or something else?

Comment: i would like to do something like that: robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_D);

Comment: sorry, my question is modified by admin.

Comment: I want to do something like that:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/397113/how-to-make-the-java-awt-robot-type-unicode-characters-is-it-possible

Comment: I have re-edited your post, hopefully getting it closer to your original intent. If I am wrong, please feel free to re-edit it yourself. Best of luck!

Comment: You edit is good and relevant. Thanks!

Answer (score 13):

You can't always just use the KeyEvent.VK... variable.

For example on my keyboard the "%" character is above the "5". To use a Robot to type a "5", the code would be:

```
robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_5); 
robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_5);
```

and use a Robot to type a "%", the code would be:

```
robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT); 
robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_5); 
robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_5);
robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT);
```

Answer (score 3):

If you wanted to use Robot, KeyEvent has VK_QUOTE and VK_PERIOD constants. All of these constants and more are available through the [KeyEvent API](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/event/KeyEvent.html)

Comment: @dfdsfsdfsddsgsrew: Your welcome. I think that someone over-edited your original post, removing key information, and I'm sorry about that.

Comment: No need feel sorry. Your response is really useful for me!

Answer (score 0):

Previous `Robot`s seem to be deprecated.

For the time being, for JavaFX, there's `FXRobot`

```
FXRobot robot = FXRobotFactory.createRobot(scene);
robot.keyPress(KeyCode.QUOTE);
robot.keyPress(KeyCode.PERIOD);
```

Answer (score -1):

What do you mean by "programmatically type these characters?"

You can use a backslash (`\`) to print a double-quote, but you don't need anything special for the period:

```
System.out.println("This is a quote symbol: \" and this is a period: .");
```

Output:

```
This is a quote symbol: " and this is a period: .
```

Comment: I see this isn't what you want to do.  It looks like you are looking for the keyboard-code for `KeyEvent`, which **@Hovercraft Full of Eels** provided.

Answer (score -2):

Your question is not clear, but to print the characters you can use a stream using the following snippet as a template:

System.out.println("\".");