# How to make java robot class type apostrophe '

Tags: java, key, keypress, awtrobot, apostrophe

I am having problems making the method keyPress from the java robot class press the apostrophe key.

I am looking for something like:

```
Robot robot = new Robot(); 
robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_APOSTROPHE);
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Java doesn't have `KeyEvent.VK_APOSTROPHE`

Try:

```
robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_QUOTE);
```

or

```
robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_BACKQUOTE);
```

if you want the key above <Tab>

**Edit:**
The above applies to java up to [Java SE 8](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/).

From Java 9 it appears the KeyEvent.VK_### fields are no longer the way to access keystrokes.  Based on [this answer to a related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6641962/use-a-robot-to-type-characters-in-java/6642004#6642004) something like this may be the new way:

```
FXRobot robot = FXRobotFactory.createRobot(scene);
robot.keyPress(KeyCode.QUOTE);
// or robot.keyPress(KeyCode.BACK_QUOTE);
```

Comment: Thanks for the qick reply! I know there is no VK_APOSTROPHY, it was just something in that format that I needed and this worked great! I can get back to my application now...

Comment: This throws an IllegalArgumentException saying that the keycode is invalid

Comment: @mcalex, actually I prefer using regular robots. Most of the `KeyEvent.VK_###` fields work, for some reason the apostrophe key was called `VK_DEAD_ACUTE` (in my case at least) and in order to type a double quote I just had to press shift first.