# How to type 'a' using robot.pressKey?

Tags: java, keyboard

It seems the robot.pressKey(KeyEvent.VK_A) could only type 'A'. How can I type the lower letter 'a' then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`robot.pressKey(KeyEvent.VK_A)` press the keyboard key <kbd>A</kbd> which is a lower 'a' without pressing <kbd>Shift</kbd>.

Answer (score 1):

The question section will help you in this:
[How to make the Java.awt.Robot type unicode characters? (Is it possible?)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/397113/how-to-make-the-java-awt-robot-type-unicode-characters-is-it-possible)

(if you're satisfied with ascii chars)