# Java Robot with Azerty vrs Qwerty

Tags: java, keyevent, awtrobot, qwerty

I hope this isn't a duplicate, but I've scoured the forums and have yet to find any answers.

I am having issues with my java application using the Robot class to type text.  The text is provided and the application types it out.  When the user has a QWERTY keyboard everything works fine.  When the user has an AZERTY keyboard the values come out incorrectly.

For example feeding "1234567890" into the software types "&é"'(§è!çà"

I'm hoping some people have an idea how to support multiple keyboard layouts.  Thank you in advance.

Here is a snippet

```
String TRANSLATION_SHIFT = "~!@#$%^&*()_+{}|:\"<>?";
String TRANSLATION_NON_SHIFT = "`1234567890-=[]\\;',./";
Robot robot = new Robot();
String text = "1234567890";
int key;
for (char c: text.toCharArray()){
  switch(c){
    ....
    case '0':
      key = KeyEvent.VK_0;
      break;
case '1':
  key = KeyEvent.VK_1;
  break;
...(etc etc)...
case '9':
  key = KeyEvent.VK_9;
  break;
    ...
  }
  robot.keyPress(key);
  robot.keyRelease(key);
}
```

There is also code in there to

Answer (score 2):

I think you will need to be aware of the Keyboard layout, I am not sure if there is some built-in function to specify the locale to the `Robot` class, but you can find an wrapper implementation for `Robot` class that support different keyboard layouts [see this library](https://code.google.com/p/windowlicker/source/browse/trunk/src/core/main/com/objogate/wl/#wl/robot)

Comment: The linked repository is dead nowadays. It hardly hosts any material any more. Is there an updated link available?

Comment: I think the project has moved to github. The keyboard relevant part is in https://github.com/holgerbrandl/windowlicker/tree/master/src/core/main/com/objogate/wl/keyboard