# Java Robot class press special letter?

Tags: java, keycode, awtrobot

I have problem with pressing a special letter (Chinese, cyrillic etc.) via java robot class. I hava a method to press keys which works as alt+keycode. I cant convert some special letters to corrent keycode. So how can I solve it. Thanx

For Example:

```
     KeyStroke ks = KeyStroke.getKeyStroke('a', 0);
     System.out.println(ks.getKeyCode());
     Output : 97
     //but if I convert 'ş' to keycode
     //Output is 351 . So alt+351= '_' The Correct combination is alt+0254 for 'ş'
```

KeyPress:

```
public static void doType(int a, int keyCodes)
        throws AWTException {
    Robot robot = new Robot();
    robot.keyPress(VK_ALT);
    robot.keyPress(keyCodes);
    robot.keyRelease(keyCodes);
    robot.keyRelease(VK_ALT);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

'a' evaluates to 97 in [UTF-8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8).

```
    KeyStroke.getKeyCode()
```

simply returns an integer representation of 'a'.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/397113/how-to-make-the-java-awt-robot-type-unicode-characters-is-it-possible