# How to type Unicode character via Robot

Tags: java, awtrobot

How to type unicode character via robot in cross platform way ? I've seen solutions to this but only works on Windows eg: [How to make the Java.awt.Robot type unicode characters? (Is it possible?)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/397113/how-to-make-the-java-awt-robot-type-unicode-characters-is-it-possible/5092096#5092096),
Is there a way to do this on Linux and Mac ?

Comment: The solution you posted is kind of a hack that utilizes the windows keyboard combinations to unicode characters, I wouldn't use it anyway as it is not really flexible. Why don't you create a Map with all the characters and let the robot copy and paste them in case you are trying to write a unicode character?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it's your goal to write something into an input field for example, this could probably work:

```
// Set desired character
String c = "ä";
StringSelection selection = new StringSelection(c);
// Copy it to clipboard
Clipboard clipboard = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard();
clipboard.setContents(selection, null);
// Paste it
robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_V);
robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_V);
robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
```

Basically simulating a copy paste, but it will delete your current clipboard content, unless you save it. Under Mac OS you want to use `VK_META` instead of `VK_CONTROL`. Also, this will not work if you really have to simulate the keypress itself, only if you want to output it.

Comment: Awesome!, But I think you should replace String with StringSelection